# PHP Regex, Failure to skip brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to find a pattern " and b_start in (ANYTHING)" and replace it with an empty string. The following code of mine does not work; i'm afraid it's due to the brackets in the pattern. Can anyone help to point out what's wrong with it? Many thanks.

```
$a=" and b_start in (2,3,5,6...) and b_end in (4,5,3,4,5...)";
$b=preg_replace("/ and b_start in \(.*\)/", "", $a);
```

I expect $b to return " and b_end in (4,5,3,4,5...)";

Comment: Make the `\(.*\)` non greedy `\(.*?\)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make you regex lazy, by default it is greedy in nature so it will match as much as possible [`Regex Ref`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap)

```
/ and b_start in \(.*?\)/
```

---

```
$a=" and b_start in (2,3,5,6...) and b_end in (4,5,3,4,5...)";
$b=preg_replace("/ and b_start in (.*?)/", "", $a);

echo $b;
```